# identify if exponential distribution is a good model

Tags: statistics

I must identify if for a specific data set, the exponential distribution is a good model. Without using any plot. So what i was thinking is, to see if in the data set the rate of events is constant. To do that, I would sample my data many times and see if the rate of events are changing. Is that enough?

Comment: So your question is whether there is another distribution with a constant rate?

Comment: no if the exponential distribution is a good model for one specific data set.